# Select all checkboxes when I just select one of them in type script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of checkboxes. I'm displaying them in HTML code like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="ControllerModel">
  <div *ngFor="let controller of ControllerModel" class="panel col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span>
          {{controller.controllerDisplayName}}
      </span>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div *ngFor="let action of controller.actionsVM" class="col-auto my-1">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  id="customControlAutosizing">
          <label class="custom-control-label"  for="customControlAutosizing">{{action.displayName}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I select one of them, all of them are selected.

What's the problem? How can I solve this?

**Edit**

**Click on Label for see my problem . click on a1 or a2 or a3  , . . .**
[Smaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsm4hn?file=angular.json)

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz replicating the issue?

Comment: @JasonWhite i update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the stackblitz you've linked it seems you try to bind the checked state to a text field (**`action.name`**). This is truthy and will result in all checkboxes being ticked. Rather, add a **`boolean`** field to your **`ActionModel`** to bind the checked state:

```
export interface Actionmodel {
    displayName:string;
    name:string;
    isChecked:boolean; // Needed to bind the checked state
    metaData:string;
}
```

Then bind the checked state with ngModel to your model:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlAutosizing" [(ngModel)]="action.isChecked">
```

And set the initial value of **`isChecked`** to false, for example:

```
...
{
  displayName: "a1",
  name: "a1",
  isChecked: false,
  metaData: "a1",
}
...
```

The problem with the labels now is that they all refer to the same id, and that all the checkboxes have the same id as well. To make sure the labels select the proper checkboxes, use the index in your ngFor to make the ids unique within the div:

```
<div *ngFor="let action of controller.actionsVM; let i = index" class="col-auto my-1">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{'customControlAutosizing' + controller.controllerName + i}}" [(ngModel)]="action.isChecked">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{'customControlAutosizing' + controller.controllerName + i}}">{{action.displayName}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: since you have two divs with checkboxes, append **`controller.controllerName + i`** to the input ids

Check out a working demo here: [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zop3rj)

Comment: still have problem . Click on a3 to see that a1 is selected . `click on label not check box`

Answer (score 2):

Add `ngModel` for checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  id="customControlAutosizing" [(ngModel)]="action.checkBox_property">
```

Comment: not worked . when load the page all checkboxes are selected